# python dataframe latest x rows of each entry in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Need to select the latest x purchases of every client.

Is there a performant way to select the latest x rows for every client? Say we have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
df1 = 
Client Product ID
A      1       330
B      1       15
A      5       329
A      3       328
A      2       327
B      6       14
A      7       326
A      7       325
C      9       205
C      3       204
C      2       203
C      1       202
C      1       201
B      2       13
B      2       12
B      2       11
```

were ID is just an incremental id (meaning the id gives you the number of the purchase that the client has made) and we want to select the last two purchases for every client so that the output would look like this:

```
df2=
Client Product ID
A      1       330
A      5       329
B      1       15
B      6       14
C      9       205
C      3       204
```

is it possible to do this without looping through the dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the dataframe by `ID` in descending order, group by `Client` and "pick" the first 2 rows of each group.

```
df1.sort_values('ID', ascending=False).groupby('Client').head(2)

Client  Product   ID
     A        1  330
     A        5  329
     C        9  205
     C        3  204
     B        1   15
     B        6   14
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very much. Maybe you can help me with another question: Now that I have the latest x values it might be that there is a client who has less than x entries, in this case is it possible to fill up the data with a specified value for product? Explicitly say Client D's largest ID is 1 and I am still lokking for the latest 2 rows. Would it be possible to add a row which says Client = 'Client C' and Product = '500' (ID does not matter)